# Async load/ready image(sets) on background up to X GB

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm new to C# / VisualStudio and I'm trying to get a grip on async programming.

Specifically I'm writing an image viewer that should be able to show images from N multiple sets (folders) at the same time, thus using N pictureboxes. I want the image sets / folders to load in the background, thus async, and up to some maximum buffer size. Each picturebox shows a slideshow of sorts, thus while background loading the loaded images should be iterated through to be shown.

The loading should be balanced out over the sets, such that after set[i] image[j] is loaded, set[i+1] image[j] is loaded. However, since sets can change during viewing, it could be the case that for set[i] first images [1, 2 .. j] should be loaded before set[i+1][image[j+1] is loaded, as to be 'balanced' again.

(Also, I'm trying to write a bit cleaner code now, so ideally the loader can be implemented in a seperate (static) class as to not write all serious logic in my Form.)

The balancing part should be easy enough ; the async loading -- not so much. I' ve looked at several examples here at StackOverflow, but I'm doing something wrong. My GUI hangs when loading images, slideshows do not continue .. Thus clearly indicating the async isn't implemented as it should. Also, most examples I seem to find deal with async loading from websites or such - I just want to load from a local disk.

---

As for what I tried:

(I managed to reinstall my laptop WITHOUT backing up my code.. But it was garbagey anyway.)

In words then, I created several List as members of the form. Some button showed a folder browser, saving the filenames to another list. Then the latter list was iterated through, using the filenames as to start async loading the image, thereby incrementally populating the first list(s). When a timer fired a click, and when the list(s) were not empty, picbox1 showed a pic from list1, etc. I specifically did not use async load of the pictureboxes - I need to process the images before showing them. (For instance, resizing manually, not by means of the textbox. I need this as I want to 'scroll' through images when they are shown, as to maxime the use of screen estate.)

At the lowest level, it was something like `async Image.loadfromfile()` Followed by `await`. I did not use `Task`.As I read that you need to 'propagate' the async stuff to all above functions, I (believe I) used the async keyword in all above functions. So, the functions actually loading as well as for instance the function button_click had the async keyword. I can't remember if I used async in my top Application file, where the form is actually ran in the Main () loop - nor do I really understand if Main SHOULD be async too. -- Same for the `await` / `Task` keyword ; I might have used / avoided to use this incorrectly.

What I was expecting to happen was that the loading of images continued on the background, while the already loaded images could be started to be iterated through as to show them in the picboxes as slideshow. However, the GUI clearly hanged.

(-- I hope this is specific enough for the standards here. (Also new to StackOverflow.) If not, I will try to implement it again using a static class and then call for help again with specific code.)

Comment: Please refer to [ask] to improve the question. As is, it will not create useful answers. As is, the best we could say is "yep. Prolly something wrong."

Comment: Okay, I will do so. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.